# Loop throttled with Thread.sleep() runs more than twice as often as intended

Tags: java

I use the following loop (cut some stuff out) as the main loop for a game, but I can't get it to throttle down to a speed I want it to, it keeps running about twice as fast as I intend.

```
private void myLoop() throws InterruptedException {

    long timer = TimeUtils.getMillis();

    int achievedLoops = 0;

    long currTime = 0l;
    long loopTime = 0l;
    long lastTime = TimeUtils.getNano();

    while(!isRequestedToStop) {
        currTime = TimeUtils.getNano();
        loopTime = currTime - lastTime;
        lastTime = currTime;

        if(TimeUtils.getDeltaMillis(timer) > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            logger.debug(achievedLoops + " Loops");
            achievedLoops = 0;
        }

        achievedLoops++;

        if(loopTime < TIME_PER_LOOP) {
            Thread.sleep( (TIME_PER_LOOP - loopTime) / 1000000l);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternative implementation of the sleeping, gets slightly better results (loop runs only 1.9 times too often):

```
while(loopTime < TIME_PER_LOOP) {
    Thread.sleep(1l);
    loopTime += 1000000l;
}
```

Another alternative:

```
while(loopTime < TIME_PER_LOOP) {
    Thread.sleep(1l);
    loopTime = TimeUtils.getNano() - lastTime;
}
```

**Why does that happen?

Are there any other ways to throttle a thread down?**

I basically could run it uncontrolled as the logic is tied to timed steps, but I would like to reduce the total runs of the loop as otherwise there's a marginal chance of it doing damage to a CPU..

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a `java.util.Timer`?

Comment: What is the value of `TIME_PER_LOOP`?

Comment: @Kevin the easiest would be to say that I simply did not think of it - so probably half of the question is answered now already :)

Comment: @JimGarrison 4'000'000 when I aim to have 250 runs a second (e.g. 1'000'000'000 / runsPerSecond)

Comment: Actually, you'd better use a ScheduledExcutorService (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29). It fixes some defects of java.util.Timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you perform the division

```
(TIME_PER_LOOP - loopTime) / 1000000l
```

You are truncating the result and sleeping up to 1ms less than you expect (average 0.5ms). Given your 4ms loop time, this would easily cause your loop to run twice as fast as you expect.  As others have mentioned, there are much better ways to control timing.

Comment: So how high would the target time need to be in order for it not to truncate that much? Because I register the same behaviour when I aim towards 100 loops or even less

Comment: The problem is a result of the fact that `sleep()` only has millisecond precison.

Answer (score 1):

[LockSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html) can disable the scheduling of a thread for a specified number of nanoseconds.

```
LockSupport.parkNanos(TIME_PER_LOOP - loopTime);
```

But as others have mentioned there are better ways to control timing (e.g. ScheduledExecutorService).